# List numbers with bullet

Tags: math-mode

How can I write numbers with empty bullet on top of them for a list:

I am trying to write  `$1^{\bullet}$`.

Thank you!

Comment: What's an empty bullet? Something like `\circ`? and which `list`?

Comment: So you want your bullet numbers to have... a halo?

Comment: yes a circle on the right top.think about wrinting  1^(23) but instead of 23 it would be circle .I used for a list

Comment: [Like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8xqYj.png) First or second list?

Comment: Are you trying to write abbreviations for primero, segundo, etc., like 1º, 2º, 3º or 1ª, 2ª, 3ª? You can use `$1^{\text{o}}$` and `$1^{\text{a}}$` (in math mode) or `1\textsuperscript{o}` and `1\textsuperscript{a}` (in text mode)

Comment: @Alenanno: the O.P. must be a Pythagorician :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you want a `quando` style numbering, which can easily be obtained with `\textsuperscript`,  and additionally with the `soul`package for a variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\def\quando{\textsuperscript{\ul{o}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*\textsuperscript{o}]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*\quando, before=\setuloverlap{-0.8pt}\setul{0.8pt}{0.4pt}]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you call it "quando"?

Comment: It's from ‘primo’, ‘secundo’, ‘tertio’, &c. It is also the name of a similar  command in the the `efrench` package.

Comment: Is that French then? I didn't know.

Comment: I have no idea whether it is purely French. Maybe it also exists in Italian or Sapnish. Anyway, primo, secundo, &c. are Latin.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but googling it, I was getting French-related results. :D

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways, a `direct` one with `label={\arabic*$^{\circ}$}` or more complicated, but somewhat more configurable, by defining a new `\circlebullets` 'counter' type evaluated by `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\circlebullets#1{%
  \bfseries\number\value{#1}$^{\circ}$%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\circlebullets}{\@circlebullets}{Foooo}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\circlebullets*}]
\item First  
\item Anotherone
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\item F
\item G
\item H
\item I
\item J
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries\arabic*$^{\circ}$}]
\item First  
\item Anotherone
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\item F
\item G
\item H
\item I
\item J
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that is a Spanish document, and you want ordinals, you should avoid symbols like empty bullet as `\circ`,`\degree`,etc. Instead, use a  small "o" because is a abbreviation ("primero" = 1.º, etc.). For this reason, in Spanish [should be preceded by a dot](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz#6d) (i.e., 1.º, not 1º) according to RAE rules.

However,  `1.\textsupercript{o}` is not very elegant. With `babel` and the `spanish` option you can use alternatively `1\sptext{o}` or the shorhand `1"o` that include the dot and adjust space and height conveniently, also in enumerate environments:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem,textcomp}
\begin{document} 
\noindent 
1$^{\circ}$  $\neq$  
1\textdegree\ $\neq$ 
1º $\neq$ 
1\textsuperscript{o} $\neq$  
1.\textsuperscript{o} $\neq$  
1\sptext{o} = 
1"o
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*"o]
   \item First
   \item Second
   \item Third
   \item Fourth
   \item Fifth
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```